# selecting data and specific value from two different values

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know what's wrong with my code, can anybody help me? i have two tables rsales and salessumarry, and let say i have this ff value for my tables.

data from salessumarry

```
receipt | date      | mode_payment | register_mode |
0000012 |09/28/2013 |     cash     |   sales       |
```

date from rsales

```
name | description |  category    |  receipt  |
33uf |    10v      |   capacitor  |  0000012  |
ic   |   ic12      |    icc       |  0000012  |
```

my problem is this. i am creating a report and i want to select all data depending on the range of date selected by the admin. so let say i choose to select all register_mode = "sales"  and date from salessumarry
from  09/28/2013  to  09/28/2013. so the hard part for me is how can i select values from my "rsales" in which "receipt" from salessumarry = "receipt" from rsales. take note that only specific values i want to select from rsales such as "name" and  "description" .

i have this following code but don't know if this structure of inner join is valid. please help me

```
$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT salessumarry .*, name as name ,description as description FROM salessumarry LEFT JOIN rsales  ON rsales.receipt = salessumarry.receipt 
LEFT JOIN rsales  ON rsales.sales = salessumarry.sales  
LEFT JOIN rsales  ON rsales.date  BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
LEFT JOIN salessumarry  ON salessumarry.date  BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'  ");
```

Comment: Your query uses lots of columns that you don't show in the tables. Do you really have a `date` column in both tables?

Comment: i dont have date in rslaes. only in salessumarry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT s.*, r.name, r.description
FROM salessummary s
JOIN rsales r ON s.receipt = r.receipt
WHERE s.register_mode = 'sales'
AND s.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
```